# Can an Excel file be used as a calculation engine for a Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx, calculation, exceljs

I will be making a POST request to `/api/vehicles` with the body values: make, model, year, etc.  The goal is to have these values entered into an existing excel calculator file as inputs so that an output (as a result of excel formulas) is generated which can be stored in a database. The excel file will be used as a calculation engine.

I'm currently using the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) npm package to read and modify the excel file. To recalculate, I attempted to use the [xlsx-calc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-calc) npm package after changing a few cell values but it is not recalculating the workbook.

The problem is that excel won't recalculate the workbook. Is it possible to use excel on the backend in this way? What options do I have?

Here is vehicles route that doesn't work. the function call of `XLSX_CALC(workbook)` is where it hangs and doesn't send back a response:

```js
const express = require('express');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const XLSX_CALC = require('xlsx-calc');
const formulajs = require('@formulajs/formulajs');

const router = express.Router();

let directKeys = {};
directKeys['GAMMA.INV'] = formulajs.GAMMA.INV;
XLSX_CALC.import_functions(formulajs, { override: true });
XLSX_CALC.import_functions(directKeys);

const workbook = XLSX.readFile('backend/excel/testcalc.xlsx');
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[8]];

router.post('/api/vehicles', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { user_id, mileage } = req.body;
    worksheet['B12'].v = mileage;
    XLSX_CALC(workbook);
    const summary = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
    res.send(summary);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.status || 500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't expect anyone to be able to "fix" the xlsx-calc package. I'm looking for advice on how to use excel as a calculation engine

Comment: [GitHub Issue #89](https://github.com/fabiooshiro/xlsx-calc/issues/89)

Answer (score 3):

My advice - don't use Excel for this. Take a look at one of the pure-JS alternatives such as Handsontable or SpreadJS which will do recalculation either in NodeJS or in the browser as desired.

SpreadJS will be able to load an Excel file and handle the calculations, even if they're quite involved. SpreadJS will also work in AWS Lambda so you can do very high levels of concurrency if you need to (depending on the rest of your architecture). We do multi-statement financial forecast models with this so they can get quite involved. The scalability for large sheets isn't great compared with Excel though. Our biggest spreadsheets are <10,000 rows and I really wouldn't recommend this for anything more than 100,000 rows.

I haven't had direct experience with Handsontable but I know it's somewhat similar and there are other alternatives out there.

These are commercial offerings so there is a cost involved. If the computations are simple and don't change much, luke's advice to rewrite the functions in pure JS may be preferable.

Comment: Hi Richard,

Thanks for mentioning SpreadJS, appreciate it. I'm the SpreadJS PM. Would you mind sending an email addressed to me at us.sales@grapecity.com? I have a couple questions to see how we can help improve your performance issues, thank you.

Kevin Ashley

Answer (score 2):

Excel will try to recalculate the minimum amount of formulas whenever a cell is edited, and it's unclear whether the formulas will recalculate when xlsx-calc changes a cell (rather than a user). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264398/when-and-how-does-excel-recalculate-its-formulas).

You can try enabling [automatic recalculation](https://www.pryor.com/blog/why-is-your-excel-formula-not-calculating/#:%7E:text=Check%20for%20Automatic%20Recalculation,you%20change%20a%20cell%20value.) in your workbook, but if that doesn't work, it might be time to start thinking about writing the operations that the excel sheet does in pure javascript. Using excel as a calculation engine doesn't make sense to me if you're storing these values in a database. It's a bit like trying to build a calculator that depends a slide rule to function.

If your workbook is extremely involved, the workaround is to have a function that searches for cells with a formula and refreshes them by re-writing the formula into the cell (see the link in anolan23's comment on the question). This can be incredibly inefficient depending on the size and complexity of your excel workbook.