After exporting the SSRS report to excel which has totals, Can we again recalculate the values of total by deleting any row in excel
I created a report in visual studio and the report has total of many columns. I need to export the report to excel and then If I delete any row from the excel sheet the excel should automatically calculate the totals.
I am not getting the solution so did not try anything as of now.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264398/when-and-how-does-excel-recalculate-its-formulas

Out of the box, you cannot do this. When SSRS exports to excel it just puts formatted values into cells, that's it. The totals you export are just numbers, not formulae.

You could try exporting your data to an excel template with SSIS.
